# save zipped file directly from the web in r

Tags: r

I am trying to save a zip file from the internet onto my computer. I can download the content straight into R with:

```
sfile <- "http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smaccal1/ARCLake/v3_0/PL/ALID0001.zip"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(sfile,temp)
```

From here, how can I then save that zipped file on my computer without having to open it in R by unzipping the folder and then using read.table

```
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "a1.dat"))
unlink(temp)
```

and then save that data. Essentially I would like to save the files directly from the web (still zipped). How can this be done?

Comment: Isn't that what you're `temp` file is? You're downloading the zip file to that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `download.file` to save the file in a specified location:

```
sfile <- "http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smaccal1/ARCLake/v3_0/PL/ALID0001.zip"
download.file(sfile, destfile = "/path/to/myfile.zip")
```

Comment: dang! people getting all sorts of hats I'm not finding yet :-)